# How to distinguish user-interactive tasks and batch tasks in 'CFS' scheduler?

Tags: batch-file, task, scheduler, interactive

How to distinguish user-interactive tasks and batch tasks in 'CFS' scheduler?

Scheduler always allocate priority on the tasks depending on characteristic of tasks.

And, my question is how scheduler knows these characteristic of tasks.

Some reference inform me there is some kind of heuristic to distinguish which one is user interactive task or not.